# Help identifying version of solitaire

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

I was taught a solitaire game similar to klondike that has seven columns, 1st row has 1st card up and next 6 columns down, second layer has column 1 and 2 up next 5 down, erc until the 7th row is all face up leaving 3 cards in your hand.   Alternate red/black and a column can be moved whether it is sorted below a given card or not.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what makes this any different from klondike? What is the objective?

Comment: @GendoIkari Klondike has only the first card in each column up, and decreasing number of cards in each column, leading 24 cards to play through.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Ah I just didn't read carefully enough; mixed up "row" and "column" in the original text (and missed the bit where all columns have the same number).

Comment: Sounds like the same game sought here: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/48062/identify-this-standard-deck-solitaire-with-a-7x7-tableau

Comment: This seems like the same one, as well: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/50541/can-anyone-identify-this-variant-of-yukon-solitaire