# Can anyone identify this variant of Yukon solitaire?

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

I learned this game from my grandfather, and I want wondering if anyone else has seen it before or knows the name of it. I think it is a [Yukon variant](https://www.bvssolitaire.com/rules/yukon.htm).

- **Deck**: one deck with no jokers (52 cards).
- **Deal**: The Tableau is filled with 7 piles containing 7 cards each: Moving left to right deal one card face up and 6 face down to form 7 rows. Then, on top of those cards from left to right deal 2 face up and 5 face down. Then from left to right deal 3 face up and 4 face down, so on and so forth until there is a face up card dealt on the rightmost stack. The 3 leftover cards can be played at any time.
- **Play**: same way as standard Yukon, where stacks of cards can be moved around as long as the destination card is opposite suit and one rank higher.
- **Goal**: Build the 4 foundations piles from Aces to Kings.

Any wisdom on this would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: maybe you can find it at this list of ~545 Solitaire games: https://www.bvssolitaire.com/rules/

Answer (score -1):

My mom and I also played this version. She called it Long Solitaire. I have looked for this version online but haven’t been able to find it. I still play it with real cards.